# inherit from template class and using inherit its constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, inheriting-constructors

i want to inherit a template class, and use "using" to inherit its constructor. But when i call the move constructor, fail in "no matching constructor"

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename ARG>
class TBase {
 public:
  TBase() {}
  TBase(TBase<ARG>&& t) {}

 private:
  ARG arg;
};

class Int : public TBase<int> {
 public:
  using TBase<int>::TBase;
};

int main() {
  TBase<int> t1;
  Int t2(std::move(t1));
  return 0;
}
```

the build result

```
 In function 'int main()':
20:23: error: no matching function for call to 'Int::Int(std::remove_reference<TBase<int>&>::type)'
20:23: note: candidates are:
13:7: note: Int::Int()
13:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
13:7: note: Int::Int(Int&&)
13:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::remove_reference<TBase<int>&>::type {aka TBase<int>}' to 'Int&&'
```

Comment: t1 is `TBase<int>`, not `Int`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the problem is simple to explain:

Default-, Copy- and Move- ctors are special. They are not inherited by inheriting ctors. For the details, [read more about inheriting constructors here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/using_declaration).

So, write your own ctor accepting a baseclass-instance. Shouldn't be too hard, as you try to simply inherit ctors.

Comment: Thanks, i know it works in write own ctor. I know the copy and move are special now!!!!

Comment: This is true in C++11 and C++14, but I'm not certain about C++17. As far as I can see from cppreference and N4659, the code should be valid in C++17, but clang++ 7.0.0 trunk 330177 with -std=c++17 still rejects it with the same errors.

Comment: Aha - this is covered by CWG issue 2356: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#2356 . I think the status of "tentatively ready" means the group has at least looked at it and agreed there is a problem with the C++17 wording.